# What approach is to be taken to convert a code snippet to simple English?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, nlp

Suppose `a` is a variable and I have a DSL (Domain Specific language) or a code snippet that says

`a.size() > 0`

My task is to convert it to simple English and print `Number of a's is greater than zero`

**More examples:**

**Input**:  `a != null` , **Output** `a is not null`

**Input**:  `a != ""` , **Output** `a is not empty`

**Input**: `a.parent.children.size()>3`, **Output**: `Parent of 'a' has more than 3 children`

**Input**: `a.children().forAll(e|e.value<4)`, **Output**: `All the children of 'a' have a value less than 4`

I want to know what the right approach to this kind of problem would be.

I basically want to translate the code snippet to simple English, similar to how humans can have a fair/high level understanding of what the code snippet is trying to do by just reading it.

I've considered the below approaches:

1. One approach that I've considered to to write something like a compiler or a parser.
2. Another approach that I'm considering is to use machine translation, similar to how RNNs are used to translate one language to another.

How would one approach this problem?

I asked the same question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48814273/what-approach-is-to-be-taken-to-convert-a-dsl-to-simple-english) but I didn't get any response yet, so decided to ask here

Comment: Either of your approaches would be valid. If your DSL is strict, then a parser would be preferred, as this gives some guarantees of correctness that would be difficult to demonstrate with a RNN. Unfortunately, if you want either approach explained in detail, that is far too broad for a Stack Exchange question . . . which is probably why you are not getting a response. Could you add some detail about where you are stuck? That might turn it into a better question - although it might also just confirm that we cannot answer here.

Comment: @NeilSlater Thanks for your response, my DSL is strict. I know its a little broad for SE, but i just wanted to know what the approach would be, and the best practices as I've never dealt with problems like these. This is all the requirement I have and I need to know in what direction to start with

Comment: Asking generally about "best practices" likely will not get you very far on Stack Exchange. I suggest try to start with a parser based approach then ask a specific question about that when you get stuck. If you are stuck before you start, then you need to find a tutorial, book or course on the subject in order to structure your learning, before you get into asking questions on a site like this.